# Removing a Button in Standard Toolbar if already found in Outlook

Tags: c#, outlook, add-in

I have added a button to the standard toolbar of Main Outlook Window . It works when I build the Outlook Project. But whenever I again build the project, the button replicates again in the Main Outlook Window.

My code here:

```
private void AddToolbar()
    {
        if (cbar == null)
        {
            cbar = this.Application.ActiveExplorer().CommandBars["Standard"];
        }
        try
        {
            Office.CommandBarButton btn = (Office.CommandBarButton)cbar.Controls.Add(1, missing, missing, missing, missing);
            btn.Caption = "button1";
            btn.Tag = "button1";
            if (this.firstButton == null)
            {
                this.firstButton = btn;
                firstButton.Click += new Office._CommandBarButtonEvents_ClickEventHandler(ButtonClick);
            }
        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

How to add the remove functionality for this button if already found?

Comment: thinkcool, May I suggest that you retag your question? As far as I can tell, you're asking about tweeking Outlook, not Visual Studio. Right?

Comment: I am using Visual Studio for development..

Comment: Right, but I don't think your IDE has much bearing on the question itself. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to check if `firstButton` is null before creating another button. Something like:

```
        if (this.firstButton == null)
        {            
            Office.CommandBarButton btn = (Office.CommandBarButton)cbar.Controls.Add(1, missing, missing, missing, missing);
            btn.Caption = "button1";
            btn.Tag = "button1";

            this.firstButton = btn;
            firstButton.Click += new Office._CommandBarButtonEvents_ClickEventHandler(ButtonClick);
        }
```

Comment: I tried this, this does not work. I tried to replicate the idea given at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms269110%28v=VS.90%29.aspx for removing..But stuck up ..

Comment: So even when you check to see if firstButton is null before creating a new button, it still results in a duplicate button? Hmm.... my guess is that something else beyond the code you've posted is causing firstButton to get garbage collected.